# Can you add a constraint that the Attribute can only be added to a property with public getter and setter in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, setter, getter

In C#, you can limit the scope of an attribute with the `AttributeTargetAttribute`. This constraint is checked at compile time.

Is there a way to force that if the target is a `AttributeTargets.Property`, that both the getter and setter must be public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at compile-time. If you did this via reflection in the attribute, then you could enforce it at runtime. My question is: why do you want to enforce this?

Comment: Since I want to call the getter and setter using reflection. Of course you can check such constraints at runtime. However it is more convenient to do this at Compile time since this prevents one from making mistakes.

Comment: I'd strongly reconsider your design, as this has a "code smell" to it, but anyway my answer stands - you can't do it with attributes at compile-time.

Comment: Well I'm implementing some kind of serializer like the `XmlSerializer`. I don't see how you can set values of an instance where you don't know anything about it's class.